# Indesign XML export generates points at the begining of each node?

Tags: xml, arabic, adobe-indesign

When I try to export XML from an existing .indd file written in arabic, the phrases ending with a point or a closing bracket or other special character i find it at the begining of the XML element. Am I missing an option in Indesign? or is there anothe process to make sure the phrase is in the correct 'order'?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this character isn't typed in the next tag ? If tags are glued, then you might be fooled.
Something like this:
[image]